# How do I access the instance of an object that was loaded via storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

[image: The cube]

See that little yellow cube? That's a controller. When the main controller loads, it loads too. Now I want to get the instance of that object in the main controller and call functions in it. How do I do this?

Comment: Set up an outlet from the main controller to the other controller.

Comment: What type of outlet? Is it considered a UIViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a property on your View Controller class and wire it up by control + clicking on the cube.

So in your header file, create something like:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet MyObjectClass *myObject;
```

Comment: This seems like what I want to do, but I can't specify "MyObjectClass" without #import'ing the .h, which causes it to throw errors. The class I'm dealing with for some reason only doesn't throw errors when included through storyboard?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to import MyObjectClass.h in your View controller's header file, you could use a forward declaration (@class MyObjectClass;). But including the header shouldn't cause an error. You should post some code in your original question. You also should make sure that your "cube" is an instance of MyObjectClass which you can do in the Identity Inspector.

Comment: Ah, it has something to do with the class I'm trying to include being .mm and being called from a .m